# Format date to string

Tags: sql, db2

I'm trying to format a db2 date into a string as "YYYY/MM/DD".

The best I got so far is:

```
SELECT CAST(YEAR(MYDATE) AS VARCHAR(4)) || '/'
|| CAST(MONTH(MYDATE) AS VARCHAR(2))    || '/'
|| RIGHT('00' || CAST(DAY(MYDATE) AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) FROM MYCALENDAR
```

Is there a better, terser way to do this?

ps: Toying around with locales is not an option.

Comment: Is there a _database_ reason why you're formatting the date (ie, someone is storing a string field)?  Because formatting for display is the job of the _view_ code, **not** the database.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to the [IBM documentation](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_bif_varcharformat.htm) the following should work:

```
 SELECT VARCHAR_FORMAT(MYDATE, 'YYYY/MM/DD') FROM MYCALENDAR;
```

Comment: SQL0440N  No authorized routine named "FORMAT" of type "FUNCTION" having compatible arguments was found.  SQLSTATE=42884

[ Command Line Processor for DB2 Client 9.7.1 ]

Comment: Hmpf, let me see, maybe I'm confusing something

Comment: I found the error. According to IBM the routine is called `VARCHAR_FORMAT`. I updated my answer.