# Is there a quick way to re-format all values in a ColdFusion query column?

Tags: sql, arrays, coldfusion, db2, string-formatting

I am at the liberty of a certain database, which stores date values as integers (i.e. `20121119`). I have several queries that retrieve these values for reporting displays, so I need to convert these values to `m/d/yyyy` format.

I see several ways to do this:

- Do the conversion in the display, using an existing global UDF. The drawback here, is that if the query is re-used, I need to duplicate the code necessary to convert the display value.
- Parse the value in the SQL to return a properly formatted value. I'm reading from a DB2/iSeries, which does not (as far as I have found) have a built-in function for this.
- Loop over the result set and convert each value one at a time. This is what I am currently doing, however for larger data-sets, performance is an issue:

  ```
  <cfscript>
      var i = 1;
      var _query = ARGUMENTS.query;

      if  (   !Len(Trim(ARGUMENTS.column))
          ||  !ListFindNoCase(_query.ColumnList, ARGUMENTS.column))
          return _query;

      for (i=1; i<=_query.RecordCount; i++) {
          _query[ARGUMENTS.column][i] =
              VARIABLES.Library.DateTime.ParseAS400Date(
                  _query[ARGUMENTS.column][i]
                  );
      }

      return _query;
  </cfscript>
  ```

Is there an easy/quick way to apply a formatting function to an entire column in a ColdFusion query object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted by @Dan, there is [a built-in function](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fdb2%2Frbafzscatsformat.htm) that will convert a string to a timestamp representation.  Since you have an int, then it would be something like this:

```
SELECT VARCHAR_FORMAT(TIMESTAMP_FORMAT(CAST(20121119 AS CHAR(8)), 'YYYYMMDD'), 'MM/DD/YYYY')
FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
```

Comment: This works pretty good. But, what if there's any invalid value in the column - i.e. 20100230? That's a valid integer, but cannot be converted to a date. I'm getting a `[SQL0181] Value in date, time, timestamp string not valid.` error.

Comment: the only other issue with this is that it creates a TIMESTAMP value, which I then still need to format as 'm/d/yyyy'.

Comment: There's another function, [`VARCHAR_FORMAT()`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fdb2%2Frbafzscavarcharformat.htm), which will convert from a timestamp to a character representation of your choosing (updated example)

Comment: As for `20100230`, that's not a date, so why would you expect it to be convertible to one?

Answer (score 2):

This page might help you with the parsing in db2 you didn't know about.  [Format date to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9083121/format-date-to-string)

**Edit:** Oops, you said it was an integer.  The `cast()` function will convert it to character and then you can use `concat()` and `substr()` to format it.

Using that function would be my approach.

Comment: .. and consider putting the logic into a `view` so it is easy to reuse from your cfquery's.

Comment: @Leigh - Assume I don't have control over the database - ie creating objects such as views. I probably would have created a database UDF for this if I had.

Comment: @Dan I tried parsing the value in SQL using LEFT() RIGHT() and SUBSTR(). I will try the cast as well.

Comment: @EricBelair - If it were possible, I tend to prefer views when a calculated column is used frequently or from several queries (not sure about yours). Then there is no extra handling, just a select from viewname everywhere. But since it would be scalar udf's it probably comes down to personal preference.

Comment: @Leigh, I understand what you're saying. The issue is, I have a lot of reports that select this same type of data from many tables. So, I'd have to create a view for each table I'm selecting from.

Comment: @Eric - Gotcha. I thought it might be one or two tables - shared by many queries. If it is many tables with many different date columns, then you are right. A udf is probably the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

> Do the conversion in the display, using an existing global UDF.

This is the right way to handle this problem. Typically, formatting should not be applied to a data model (which is essentially what your query result is). Formatting should be applied when the data is displayed. This allows you to format the data differently when it is displayed in different contexts. Also, it improves code readability.

> The drawback here, is that if the query is re-used, I need to duplicate the code necessary to convert the display value.

This is not a drawback. You will be formatting the data for presentation any time you are displaying data. Formatting a date is no different.

Calling a function that formats your data more than once is not "code duplication". You are simply using the formatting function as it was intended to be used.

Comment: that's the way I've been doing it. I've recently started "simplifying" things so that every report that's viewable in a web browser can also be downloaded (right now just in CSV format). So, I have a very nice, very neat, very simple global method that takes the query and dumps it into a CSV with column headers and everything. If I re-format date values (which almost every report has), I'd have to create a separate method for each report. Besides, the data is actually a date, shouldn't it come out of the query as what it represents, not the actual value?

Comment: Your solution does work-- the problem is just that you're doing it the hard way. It is much easier (and faster) to change the formatting of values as you display them via cfoutput. Rather than writing separate methods for each report, write a generic "report creator" function that will handle formatting for you.